# xfce4-notifyd doesn't start automatically, and I don't know how to start it

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, services, notification, 20.10

I'm using Xubuntu 20.10 and have noticed that no notifications come through, and when I check my notifications settings, it says "The notification service is not running. No notifications will be shown."
I did some digging and I found that the service wasn't being started automatically. xfce4-notifyd is installed, but I'm not sure how to start it (or for that matter, have it automatically start).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it on my own! I had to create a launcher in the whisker menu to run `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/notifyd/xfce4-notifyd` and set it to autostart every time I logged in.

Answer (score 2):

Notifications are handled by the xfce4-notifyd systemd service. To manually start the notification service, run:

```
$ systemctl start xfce4-notifyd.service
```

Comment: Running outputs an error: `Failed to start xfce4-notifyd.service: Unit xfce4-notifyd.service not found.`

Comment: is the `xfce4-notifyd` package installed?

Comment: Yep, however I actually did get it working.